# Viewing the directories on a remote unix machine

Tags: linux, unix

I know of the scp command to copy files from my local machine to a remote machine. What is a similar command to view the directories in a remote machine? I mean a

```
 ls -l
```

shows the files in my local unix machine. How can I view the directories in a remote unix machine? I tried

```
ls -l <username>@ip_address
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

Use `ssh` for remote commands-:

```
ssh <username>@ip_address <command>
```

E.g.

```
ssh  <username>@ip_address ls -l <dir>
```

Comment: You could even do `ssh username@remotehost` then type interactive commands on the `remotehost` terminal; type `exit` to quit the remote shell and get back to the local machine.